# Robot Framework automatically moves output files after test execution in vscode

Tags: robotframework, vscode-tasks

At the moment I'm trying to setup a automatic task on vscode to be run after I run Robot Framework test.
What I want to do is to move my output files (log, report, output) in a new directory that is named with  information that I get during execution of the test and I'm at loss on how to do it.

I first tried directly with RF (listener libraries) however the test teardown are still run as part of the test and so the logs are not written when I want to move them.

Second idea that I got is use the task that can be defined in vscode to move my files to the new directory. However I'm not accustomed with the setup of task and as I understand it it's run at the start of the run test. Also with my configuration standard task are not run as the test are launch via the Robot Framework: Run Test/Task from the module Robot Framework Language Server.

I thought that perhaps I need to split the task ? By creating Directory during test with test teardown and then find how to setup a vscode task to move the output files to the new folder ?

If some of you have some experience on how I can setup this I would be really grateful.

Comment: call robot from your own python script https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/autodoc/robot.html#robot.run.run and once that's done, move the files to where you need'em.